# Executing next else statement after some counting

Tags: c, if-statement

If x <2, than we execute some code, else if  x>2  repeats more than 5 times then we execute another code.  What is proper structure for this task?

```
int counter =0;
int=x;
if (x<2)
       doSomething;
else 
      count++
else if (count>5)
      doSomethingElse;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you wanted but I think you wanted to use 1 if 2 else if 3 else

Comment: The `int = x;` line is syntactically incorrect.  You might be after; `if (x < 2)
       doSomething();
else if (count++ > 5)
      doSomethingElse();` (or maybe `++count` — choose carefully).

Comment: What to do if `x == 2` ?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use curly braces even for one-liners.

Comment: When x<2 code block also needs to reset `count` to 0 and when `count` is greater than 5 do not increment count

Comment: regarding: `int=x;`   This doesn't compile.  Suggest: `int x;`  Note: the value in `x` will depend on what ever trash is on the stack at the location of `x`.  So the result is undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this:

```
if (x<2)
       doSomething;
else if (count <= 5)
      count++;
else
      doSomethingElse;
```

Comment: I want to execute another part of code if x<2 condition is not met more than 5 times.

Comment: The `x >- 2` test is unnecessary, since it is guaranteed to be so if x<2 fails. Also, indentation is wrong. As written, the `else` pairs with the `if (x >= 2 && count <= 5)` clause.

Comment: What do you want to do if x<2 is not met more than 5 times?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat `something()` n times, then do `something_else()`, then the best is to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WHERE_I_AM()     do{ printf("in %s\n", __func__);} while(0)

void do_something()
{
        WHERE_I_AM();
}

void do_something_else()
{
        WHERE_I_AM();
}

int main()
{
        int n_times = 5;

        while(n_times--)
                do_something();
        do_something_else();

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

which runs into

```
$ pru
in do_something
in do_something
in do_something
in do_something
in do_something
in do_something_else
$ _
```

if you want to do it like you say, that the next `else` part is executed after the number of times specified, first of all you have to clarify how many times are you going to execute the loop.  It's better if you post a complete example, as stated in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Let's say you are in a `for` loop that is going to execute 20 times... and after the fifth you want it to execute a different function.

If you change the code above by this:

```
[...]
        int n_times_first = 5;
        int n_times_total = 20;
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < n_times_total; i++) {
                if (i < n_times_first)
                        do_something();
                else
                        do_something_else();
        }

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
[...]
```

but this time you'll get 5 executions of `do_something()` and 15 more of `do_something_else()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear about when to do something else, but if you want to do something else if count>5 regardless of the value of x, try this:

```
if ( count > 5 ) {
   doSomethingElse;
} else {
   if ( x < 2 ) {
      doSomething;
   } else {
      count++;
   }
}
```